# Rounding in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, rounding

I have this query

```
(case when a.item_no >= '77000' and a.item_no <='77099' then
    (op_drill + op_machine + op_ssd + op_freight + op_paint + ((actual_tooling * 1.2))) 
    else (op_drill + op_machine + op_ssd + ((op_drill + op_machine + op_ssd) *.27) + ((op_drill + op_machine + op_ssd + op_freight + (op_curforg *1.25) + ((op_drill + op_machine + op_ssd)*.27)) * .075)+
     op_freight + (op_curforg *1.25) + op_paint) 
      end)  as new_cost,
```

it returns 10.1201575

In vb.net I can run this statement

```
 dblNewCost = Math.Round(dblNewCost, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

which returns 10.13

Is there a way to duplicate this is sql server.  I tried round(num,2) but that didn't showup correctly

Comment: Please explain: "but that didn't showup correctly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some other issue. SQL Servers ROUND() function works just like VB's. There is no way using `Math.Round(10.1201575, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` would return 10.13.  Compare the number that is being rounded on both side to make sure you are comparing apples-to-apples.